# Do ptr::copy::<u8>(src as *const u8, dst as *mut u8, size_of::<T>()) and ptr::copy::<T>(src, dst, 1) have the same performance?

Tags: rust

Do these two calls have the same performance?

```
ptr::copy::<u8>(src as *const u8, dst as *mut u8, size_of::<T>());

ptr::copy::<T>(src, dst, 1);
```

`src` and `dst` are both type `T` raw pointers, there're two ways of copying `src` to `dst`. I don't know how does rust implement `ptr::copy`, so do they have the same performance?

Comment: well, it should, since it just copies raw bytes. The type here would be used to know how may bytes should it copy. But I cant confirm.

Comment: If they did not have the same performance, wouldn't the slow one be rewritten to just call the fast one instead of whatever slow thing it was doing?

Comment: @trentᶠᵒʳᵐᵉʳˡʸᶜˡ Even if the generic function was faster, you cannot implement the non-generic using the generic.

Comment: BTW, conisder if you really need `copy()` and not `copy_nonoverlapping()`.

Answer (score 4):

The two cases you mention will have the same performance. There is no reason to compile them differently. The optimizer can easily see that your `*const u8` is actually coming from a `*const T`. And `size_of::<T>()` is also known at compile time.

The only way you could get worse performance is if your cast to `*const u8` and the `size_of` call are too far away from your `copy` call. When the compiler cannot propagate this information about the pointer and size properly.

Check out the generated assembly in those three cases: https://godbolt.org/z/h4M44977P

In any case, there is no reason not to go with the simple `ptr::copy(src, dst, 1)` version. There is a reason that `ptr::copy` is generic over `T`: it makes code simpler and less error-prone.